# How to create a new file where each new line contains some text and quoted line/step number?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, awk

I want to use a loop while creating a new file where each new line is created by one/single step: some text, then quoted step number, and then something else. I started with this code, but it does not work:

```
gawk '
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        print "begin\""i"\"text"i"end" # how to print a line break?
        >> "path/to/output.txt" 
}'
```

so I want to see

**output.txt**:

```
begin"1"text1end
...
begin"1000"text1000end
```

Please, help to solve this.

Comment: it does not work? does it shows any syntax errors? or just dosen't works , if yes , what is current output.

Comment: The gawk program freezes, no output, so I have to close the app

Comment: Put `BEGIN` after the first quote and before the first brace.

Comment: `awk` expects an input file, which you haven't provided, and it runs your commands against every line of that file - of which there are none. However, it runs a `BEGIN` block before reading any inputs `awk 'BEGIN{...}'`

Comment: Alternatively, do `seq 1 1000 | awk '{print "Hello",$1}'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: thank you, there was just something that I forgot... I posted an answer now

Comment: You can embed `\n` in the string to represent a literal newline; or you can have multiple `print` statements -- each will add a terminating newline.  For more complex print formatting, try `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to be placed inside of `BEGIN` block:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        print "begin\""i"\"text"i"end" >> "path/to/output.txt" 
}'
```

Comment: That's not strictly true.  Awk reads it standard input, and so if you don't feed it any input, it will wait for you to type something (thus appearing to hang).

Comment: @tripleee: I don't understand. The code above gives the desired output file without specifying any input file. Did you test the code posted in the answer?

Comment: It works, but the assertion that the code *needs* to be in a `BEGIN` block is incorrect. There are many workarounds, many of which would be easier to discover than this one -- not using Awk for something the shell can do would be fairly obvious.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting, really. I asked about solving a specific problem with the specified tool (awk), and I've found a working answer. Actually, I am not familiar with Unix shell and I just don't know what tool is better for this case.

Comment: Your code is OK, but you should be using `>` instead of `>>` for the output redirection since you want to create a new file not append to an existing one, or even better just run it as `awk 'BEGIN{for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) print "begin\""i"\"text"i"end"}' > "path/to/output.txt"` and let the shell handle creating the file.